Tire traction straps are difficult to remove
I recently used Tire Traction Grabbers (Trac Grabbers) to climb a muddy, bedrock hill using my 2010 Silverado 1500 4wd.

https://www.tracgrabber.com/



The Traction Grabbers worked great for adding traction; the truck drove like a tank. But the straps were difficult to remove from my winter tires afterwards.
I released the velcro straps, but the tension (and a tiny bit of velcro adhesion at the D-rings) prevented me from loosening the straps. I had to un-jam/move the rubber pads along the tires by repeatedly hitting the pads with a hammer toward the original position. That worked, but it was tedious due to the awkward angle, poor weather, and the need to drive forward a few times to put the pads in a position that was easy to hammer.
You wouldn't know it from the photo, but when I installed the straps, they were extremely tight and perpendicular to the wheel holes. The act of driving on them must have bent the rigid pads and stretched the straps to the point where they moved back on the tires.
Question:
Is there a way to make removing the straps easier?
I suppose one thing I could do is use fewer straps, reducing removal time, but reducing traction too. For what it's worth, the straps can't be used on the front wheels of this truck due to a lack of clearance. I only use the straps on the rear wheels.

I doubt fewer straps would be a good idea - the wheel would be far more likely to be in a position with none of them in contact.  Did you test whether reversing a bit loosened them? A lot of materials like straps stretch permanently initially, so you may find they're better next time

If you are stuck, remember you can lower the tire pressure to loosen them, and then reinflate to full pressure after removal.

It does help to install them very tight.  They can, however, still shift on the wheel due to the immense torque as yours did.  Especially on a very heavy vehicle.
The longer they are used the tighter they can get. Forcing them back to the original position will release all the tension in the strap and make it quite easy to remove them.  It can also help to drive in reverse once you are unstuck to release the tension and make it much easier to reposition the rubber blocks.  The final trick is to move the vehicle so that the wheel is directly on top of the rubber block which will also release the tension in the strap.
You could also try a different style of traction device for large commercial vehicles that might work better for climbing out of ravines.  They have larger blocks with two straps each and they don't shift as much under heavy loads.

I emailed this post to the manufacturer. That’s why they commented. They likely meant well, but didn’t know the rules. I have proposed some edits that remove the sales pitch but leaves the useful info in tact.

This specific point is likely the answer: ”The final trick is to move the vehicle so that the wheel is directly on top of the rubber block which will also release the tension in the strap.”

If you just grab the block by hand, you can pull it back to the original position pretty easily. The strap will then have slack and will come off easily.

OP says a hammer was required to move the blocks back to original position - I wouldn't call that "pretty easily".

I  invented them, and have used them many times and never had an issue putting them back to the original position

The ratchet strap would not work because when it gets filled with mud it's almost impossible to get off

@Brian I drove up a 200 metre muddy, rocky trail and back again with the grabbers installed. Maybe the traction grabbers aren’t normally driven that far, and not on bedrock. In this case, the traction grabbers were extremely jammed and definitely couldn’t be moved by hand. Although, @JimPerry’s suggestion of parking directly on top of a grabber would likely work; the strap would be quite loose then due to the squished tire.

What Jim said also works very well. He is my partner in this. If you have any questions feel free to contact us

I wonder if a ratchet strap would be easier to un-jam compared to the velcro D-ring straps. Ratchet straps would also be easier to fully tighten, eliminating much of the jamming problem in the first place.
Wirh that said, the ratcheting mechanism might not be positioned in a good spot which would make it difficult to install. Maybe looping the strap around the tire more than once would help. Or modify the ratchet ahead of time so that there's not so much strap between the ratchet and the hook. Ratchet strap lead is too long (eliminate strap on ratchet side)

Or eliminate the strap altogether:

VULCAN Delta Wire Hook End Fitting For 2 Inch Ratchets
VULCAN Tube Style Double J-Hook Ratchet Attachment
Various Vulcan strap hardware
